# How to add Web as a wizard, so I can create new .css in eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse, web, javafx

I just followed the instructions in the link below and downloaded Web Tools Platform (WTP) and Web Tools Platform SDK (WTP SDK) successfully.
https://cedocs.intersystems.com/atelier/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.intersystems.atelier.help%2Fhtml%2Ftasks%2Fweb-development.html
However, when I wanna new a .css file in my project by *select New > Other > Web > CSS*, I still cannot find it. What should I do? I have restarted the eclipse
[what it shows when I search css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PrTj.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the About...Installed Features list include the Eclipse Web Developer Tools? Are you on the Photon release?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the directory you want a css file in
2. Click new>other
3. Navigate to CSS file
4. Continue through the wizard, don't click "finish" until you have selected whatever template you want (if at all)